# android test package overwriting activity in other package

Tags: android

I have one normal android package with an activity A.
Now I am using a second independent test package in which I run several tests.
for testing purposes i want to create an activity B which extends the activity A,
in order to overwrite some aspects of A for testing.
but since activity B is only for testing purposes I want to keep it in the test package.

Is there any possible way for this?